# Python Pandas - Iterating and adding data to blank column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate through a dataframe, classify each row and add the output to the end of the row in a new column.

It seems to be adding the same classification to every row

```
dfMach = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/nicholas/Desktop/machineSum.csv", encoding='latin-1')
dfNew = dfMach
dfNew["Classification"] = ""

for index, row in dfMach.iterrows():
    aVar = dfMach['Summary'].iat[0]
    aClass = cl.classify(aVar)
    dfNew['Classification'] = aClass
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: `dfNew.loc[index, 'Classification'] = aClass` should works

Comment: Excellent, thank you again Jezrael! :)

Comment: But wait a second. You are trying to fill all the data in new classification with the classify value returned from first value of summary ? Will that be of any use ?

Comment: Hey, yes, that is correct. I want every value in the new column to correspond to the classified value from the summary in the row

Comment: But that ain't happening in your loop

Comment: oooooohhh..... yes, I see, it is only doing the FIRST row. I need to increase that number by 1 each time. Thank you!

Comment: May be you meant `row['Summary']` instead of `dfMach['Summary']`. Its better you go for apply

Comment: Thank you Bharath, obviously your route is simplier, but could I add a variable called 'rowInt', set it to 0, and increase it in the '.iat[] part i.e. .iat[rowInt] (Scrap that, I will just add row[Summary]! :)

Comment: Why use index when you can directly access `row['Summary']` ?

Comment: Oh ok! so I can remove the .iat part and just have row['Summary], thank you!

Comment: Yes you can also use apply to get rid of all those assignments and accessing

Comment: Hmmm, it seems need only `dfMach['Classification'] = dfMach['Summary'].apply(cl.classify)` - Bharat solution ;)

Comment: So replace the whole for loop with that code? seems a lot simplier! I will stop the program and add that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) instead of looping explicitly i.e

```
 dfMach['Classification'] = dfMach['Summary'].apply(cl.classify)
```

A couple of simple mistake to be corrected in your code and a bit of improvement i.e

```
dfNew = dfMach.copy() # dfNew = dfMach This will not let you create a new copy so you have to use dfMach.copy()

dfNew["Classification"] = ""

for index, row in dfMach.iterrows(): 
    # As @jez suggested we need to use loc for assignemnt 
    dfNew.loc[index, 'Classification'] = cl.classify(row['Summary'])
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go! :)

Comment: I understand what you mean now. Thank you!

Comment: @ScoutEU there are bit of things you need to take care of so check out the updated answer : )

Comment: Bharath, thank you for taking the time to clean up my code and for your help in this. Both you and Jezrael have been great and are reasons why I love the community on this website so much, there are no comparisons!